# How to drive my credential provider with CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials

Tags: winapi, credential-providers

I've been working on a credential provider and I've been debugging it through logging. Recently learned about `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials()` API to be able to invoke it from other than login screen or remote desktop connection. The only way at this time I can seem to get my credential to display is to set the last param to CREDUIWIN_SECURE_PROMPT. I've tried various schemes of the flags with no luck. My CP works, that's not the problem. Problem is easier debugging. Only once have I had to go to rescue mode when I made my laptop unbootable. ;) The problem with using the CREDUIWIN_SECURE_PROMPT flag is that then I don't have access to the debugger because login takes over the screen and I can't get back to my debugger. I suppose the only workaround would be to remote debug on another machine with this API, but I'd prefer not to hassle with that.

My CP is registered at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers\{55157584-ff0f-48ce-9178-a4e290901663} and the default property is "MyCredProvider" (for this example). (GUID, prop name changed to protect the guilty. Also ignore LsaString where bad things would happen on a copy--of which I'm not doing.)

Any way to get my custom CP without using the secure prompt?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <EvoApi.h>
#include <decrypt.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <Lmwksta.h>
#include <StrSafe.h>
#include <LMAPIbuf.h>
#include <LMJoin.h>
#include <wincred.h>
#include <NTSecAPI.h>

#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#pragma comment(lib, "netapi32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "credui.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "secur32")

using namespace std;


template <size_t SIZE = 256>
struct LsaString : public LSA_STRING
{

    LsaString()
    {
        MaximumLength = SIZE;
        Length = 0;
        Buffer = pBuf.get();
    }

    LsaString(LPCSTR pWhat)
    {
        MaximumLength = SIZE;
        Length = 0;
        Buffer = pBuf.get();
        Init(pWhat);
    }
    void Init(LPCSTR pWhat)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(pWhat);
        if (len >= SIZE)
            throw;
        strcpy(Buffer, pWhat);
        Length = (USHORT) len;
    }
    unique_ptr<char[]> pBuf = make_unique< char[] >(SIZE);
};

int _tmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
#if 1
    wstring me(_T("MYLOGING"));
    wstring url(_T("Header"));
    wstring message(_T("Enter credentials for ..."));

    CREDUI_INFOW credInfo;
    credInfo.pszCaptionText = url.c_str();
    credInfo.hbmBanner = nullptr;
    credInfo.hwndParent = NULL;
    credInfo.pszMessageText = message.c_str();
    credInfo.cbSize = sizeof(CREDUI_INFOW);

    ULONG authPackage = 0;

    LSAHANDLE lsaHandle;
    LsaConnectUntrusted(&lsaHandle);

    LsaString<> lsaString("MyCredProvider");
    //LsaString<> lsaString(MICROSOFT_KERBEROS_NAME_A); // works ... as far as finding in LsaLookupAuth...
    //LsaString<> lsaString(NEGOSSP_NAME_A); // works ... as far as finding in LsaLookupAuth...


    ULONG ulPackage = 0;
    LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage(lsaHandle, &lsaString, &ulPackage);

    void* pBlob;
    ULONG blobSize = 0;

    DWORD dwFlags = CREDUIWIN_GENERIC; //CREDUIWIN_SECURE_PROMPT

    CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials(&credInfo, 0, &ulPackage, NULL, 0, &pBlob, &blobSize, FALSE, dwFlags);
    if (pBlob) CoTaskMemFree(pBlob);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Some time ago I wrote a simple hook-and trace utility using SetWindowsHookExA to look into keybord input via WH_KEYBOARD_LL events. Maybe, CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials() can be tracked down in the same manner. I may post my experience (It's a topic for another question, though)

Comment: not need remote debugger. easy do this with local too. simply you need first run debugger on *WinlogonDesktop*. and how your provider handle *SetUsageScenario* with *CPUS_CREDUI* ?

Comment: @bimjhi - at first *WH_KEYBOARD_LL* work only on one desktop, where installed. not for all. at second - how this can help. even if you set self hook on winlogon desktop ?

Comment: *lsaString("MyCredProvider");* + *LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage* - have no sense in your case also

Comment: Have a look at this [code sample](https://github.com/alexyack/CredentialProviders/blob/a160c407e1049995c21c12e99c9979ba2d6e69b5/SampleCredentialInvoker/SampleCredentialInvoker.cpp#L192) and it surrounds.